# What is the smallest and fastest possible query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

What would be the fastest possible query to run in MySQL, that will allow monitoring of the basic service functioning?

A few examples I can think of:

```
SELECT NOW();
```

or

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';
```

etc..

The purpose is to execute the SQL every few minutes, so the performance is key.

Comment: Fastest is to return the const `SELECT 1;` And it should be the stored routine to avoid parsing-optimizing-translation on each invocation.

Comment: There are plenty of monitoring tools that will check the "heartbeat" of a MySQL server (or virtually any RDBMS). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Vérace As mentioned, MySQL service health. Using a monitoring tool.

Comment: If you run this every few _minutes_ it doesn't really matter whether you use `select now()` or `select 1`. If your server can't cope with a statement like that once a minute, something is seriously wrong. Another option might be [mysql_ping()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-ping.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the suggestions. By the way, the question was not about whether the server can cope with basic requests. The goal is to have the smallest possible impact on the resource usage. We don't want to be debugging server monitoring when we actually encounter performance issues in the future. We want to prevent them now.

Comment: @alph.dev  Please look at the results of this MySQL Utility script from:  https://pastebin.com/aZAu2zZ0 and provide your feedback on the possibility of using the results to pinpoint performance issues within MySQL.  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck We are not experiencing performance issues so there is nothing to pinpoint.

Comment: @alph.dev  Keep the query in mind when you are curious about where MySQL global resources are being used, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kondybas is correct; Fastest query is `SELECT 1`.

@a-horse-with-no-name is also correct "If your server can't cope with a statement like that once a minute, something is seriously wrong."

[Percona Monitoring and Management](https://pmmdemo.percona.com/) monitors MySQL servers, in some cases, once per second, without "performance issues".

Comment: Some database connection pools use this or similar statements on each connection checkout, so it can be executed a few Dozent times per second in those scenarios. The slowest about this is usually the network roundtrip.

Answer (score 1):

Probably "mysql ping" is the fastest.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php

> mysqli::ping -- mysqli_ping — Pings a server connection, or tries to reconnect if the connection has gone down

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-ping.html

Read that page on whether it necessarily auto-reconnects.